# SSSD with "ldap_id_mapping = false" will fail to start, clearing /var/lib/sss/db/* and restarting service does not resolve

Tags: ldap, active-directory, uuid, sssd

I’m working through a strange issue with SSSD on Ubuntu 18.04 - Unit is bound to the domain using Realmd, with SSSD as the primary authentication management service. If I change the line: `ldap_id_mapping = True` to `False`, I can no longer authenticate user accounts on the domain. Clearing the `/var/lib/sss/db` folder cache files and restarting sssd.service does not resolve.

User accounts are created ONLY if I let SSSD assign a new UID and GID for the user, instead of pulling the active directory POSIX entries for UID/GID.

So two questions really:

1. how do I resolve, if you know about this, and
2. my experiments are based off the understanding that different UID’s can cause permissions errors within NTFS file shares, if accessing a folder while logged in on multiple Linux platforms - attempting to unify this to mirror Mac setups on AD (same UUID/UID/GID across all logins/all machines - pulling AD posix assignments).

Question two really does I need to care about this or is it not really an issue since I’m using AD credentials to authenticate access to the files, etc. Thanks in advance for your thoughts…

---

A working version of SSSD config before making a change:

## ldap_id_mapping = False

```
[sssd]
domains = [obfuscated]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, sudo

[domain/obfuscated]
ad_domain = obfuscated
krb5_realm = obfuscated but all caps
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ldap
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
ldap_user_ssh_public_key = altSecurityIdentities
```